# How do I display variables on a 1.51 inch transparent oled display from waveshare with arduino uno?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I purchased a 1.51 inch transparent oled display on amazon. I connected it with the pin layout from the manufacturer and ran the demo. It ran perfectly, then I tried to edit the demo to have a for loop counting from one to ten and clearing the screen in between numbers. I tried to run it and it just showed some unintelligible characters. if someone could tell me how to fix the problem or point me to some documentation for the interface. I have read over and over this documentation [Waveshare Wiki Docs](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/1.51inch_Transparent_OLED#Underlying_hardware_interface) bus it is possible I missed some obvious solution there.

The code of the for loop with the clear funcion:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    Paint_DrawNum(0,0,i,&Font8, 0, WHITE,WHITE);
    OLED_1IN51_Display(BlackImage);
    Driver_Delay_ms(2000);    
    Paint_Clear(BLACK);
 }
```

And the entire arduino file:

```
#include "OLED_Driver.h"
#include "GUI_paint.h"
#include "DEV_Config.h"
#include "Debug.h"
#include "ImageData.h"




void setup() {
  System_Init();
  Serial.print(F("OLED_Init()...\r\n"));
  OLED_1IN51_Init();
  Driver_Delay_ms(500); 
  OLED_1IN51_Clear(); 

  //0.Create a new image cache
  UBYTE *BlackImage;
  UWORD Imagesize = ((OLED_1IN51_WIDTH%8==0)? (OLED_1IN51_WIDTH/8): (OLED_1IN51_WIDTH/8+1)) * OLED_1IN51_HEIGHT;
  if((BlackImage = (UBYTE *)malloc(Imagesize)) == NULL) { 
      Serial.print("Failed to apply for black memory...\r\n");
      return -1;
  }
  Serial.print("Paint_NewImage\r\n");
  Paint_NewImage(BlackImage, OLED_1IN51_WIDTH, OLED_1IN51_HEIGHT, 270, BLACK);  

  //1.Select Image
  Paint_SelectImage(BlackImage);
  Paint_Clear(BLACK);

  Paint_SetRotate(ROTATE_180);
  Paint_DrawString_EN(0, 0, "<Date Time>", &Font8, BLACK, WHITE);
  //Paint_DrawString_EN(0, 0, "10", &Font8, BLACK, WHITE);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    Paint_DrawNum(0,0,i,&Font8, 0, WHITE,WHITE);
    OLED_1IN51_Display(BlackImage);
    Driver_Delay_ms(2000);    
    Paint_Clear(BLACK);
  }
  //Paint_DrawString_EN(0, 0, i, &Font8 ,BLACK, WHITE);
  //OLED_1IN51_Display(BlackImage);
  //Driver_Delay_ms(2000);    
  //Paint_Clear(BLACK); 


  
  

  //OLED_1IN51_Clear();  
  //Paint_DrawNum(0, 0, 10, &Font8, 0, BLACK, WHITE);
  
}

void loop() {
  //Paint_DrawString_EN(0, 0, "Test Loop", &Font8, WHITE, WHITE);
}
```